# postmessage two child windows with same origin

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how to achieve proper way of communication in js (using postMessage preferably) between windows in following case:

P A R E N T
 |      |
CHILD1 CHILD2

parent is in origin1 and both childs are in the origin2 (in fact the same website in two different modes).

how to send message to exact child avoiding the second child to react.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are opening two popup windows:

```
/*
 * In window A's scripts, with A being on <http://example.com:8080>:
 */

var popup1 = window.open(...popup details...),
    popup2 = window.open(...popup details...);

popup1.postMessage('some message to popup 1', 'http://example.org');
popup2.postMessage('some message to popup 2', 'http://example.org');
```

Inside the popup window you need to add a listener code:

```
function receiveMessage(event)
{
  // Do we trust the sender of this message?  (might be
  // different from what we originally opened, for example).
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org")
    return;

  // event.source is popup
  // event.data is "some message to popup 1"
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

The catch here is that both popups need to be part of the same domain as the parent window.

Comment: Hi, actually I'm using jQuery window extension for popups but the mechanism should be the same. I tried to post messages the way you suggested but always the first window catches message. So when doing:
popup2.postMessage - popup1 gets and handles message